# How do I unlearn a word?

Tags: text, dictionary, spelling

I have accidentally learned 'formating'.

I've tried unlearning by right-click, and have removed the word from the `/Library/Spelling` and `~/Library/Spelling directories`.

The word is still not underlined in red when I type it on various apps.

Is there any way to make sure the word is unlearned?

Pages recognises the word as incorrect, but not TextEdit or Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I have (as per my post).  I've checked Local Dictionary and it is empty.  Should I just delete the file?

Comment: Yes.  Reboots and full shut offs. Let me try logging off.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround: add the correction to your Keyboard prefs.

```
SysPrefs > Keyboard > Text

formating --> formatting
```

I know it's not the ***real*** solution you want, but perhaps helps in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look here?
[ [How to delete a word accidentally added to the Pages dictionary?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28948/how-to-delete-a-word-accidentally-added-to-the-pages-dictionary?rq=1) ]

Looks like you can right-click the word and choose `unlearn`.

Comment: As per my post, yes I have tried that with no success.

Comment: You post says you removed it from the dictionaries - I assume that meant you did it manually (opening the dictionaries?) - did you mean you actually right-clicked `formating` in TextEdit or something and chose `Unlearn`?